# Autostart Manycam with specific Images via configfile or parameter

Tags: windows, command-line, webcam

At the moment I try to figure out if it is possible to start ManyCam automaticaly showing a picture i configure via a configuration file or via command line parameters.

I am afraid that this might be not possible so i also search for similary software as manycam, which enables this options. Additionally the software must run on windows.

Comment: Not a programming Q, see http://superuser.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ManyCam Support answered: It is not possible right now to start ManyCam with parameters from command line.

Answer (score -1):

The following command, when placed in a batch file, opens `manycam` when the batch file is clicked.

```
start "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\ManyCam\Bin\ManyCam.exe"
```

Comment: Your way still no specified image is loaded!